# How to implement live agent through lightning component for napili template?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, liveagent

I have already seen one video published by salesforce. In which they have used live agent button in napili template via lightning component, but how can i implement it. please share in detail.

Answer (score 1):

It will be available to us via appexchange once it passes security review .Currently the component is not available .You may reach to your salesforce AE and see if you can access the component.